# MATLAB: How do I get the value of a class property given a property name

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

If I have a class defined as

```
classdef myclass
  properties
     foo = 3;
     bar = 7;
  end
end
```

And I want to access property foo I would write

```
obj = myclass()
obj.foo % Gives me 3
```

But, if I only have a string representation of the property name, and don't know which property it is how would I do it then? As in the example below:

```
obj.someFunction('foo')  % or
someFunction(obj, 'foo') % should both give me the value of obj.foo
```

What I want to do is have a list of properties, iterate through it and get the value for a specific object.
It seems like it should be possible, but I failed to find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value = getfield(struct, 'field')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
obj = myclass();
propName = 'foo';
propValue = obj.(propName);
```

For more information, see [Generating Field Names from Variables](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) and [Dot-Parentheses](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/matlab_oop/ordinary-methods.html#brd2n2o-1).

Answer (score 0):

```
cellfun( @(prop) obj.(prop), properties(obj), 'UniformOutput', false )
```

Comment: Luckily, `getfield` solved the problem and is a bit less verbose ;)

Comment: `getfield` is fine, but `obj.(propname)` is the "modern" way. I was only doing it in a `cellfun` to show how to get all properties in one call.

Comment: Ah, I see. After reading Kavkas answer it was much clearer. Thanks!